# How to use background music in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm writting question first time at stackoverflow :D
but I'm not good at English...

Anyway, my question is here:
I'm developing NextJS web page with typescript.
I want background music on web page, but I don't know how to add it.
I tried use 'react-h5-audio-player' module, but it is maybe not support typescript version.
This module is working on local environment, but show error when 'npm run build' in aws.
I don't know why so, I will make custom audio player myself.

here is options I want:

1. autoplay basically
2. use toggle button
3. loop

And, here is my code, but not working now:

```
interface BackgroundMusicProps {
    bgmsrc: string
}

export default function BackgroundMusic({ bgmsrc }: BackgroundMusicProps) {
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    const handleAudioPlay = () => {
        const audio = new Audio(bgmsrc);
        if (playing) {
            setPlaying(false);
            audio.pause();
            console.log("pause");
        } else {
            setPlaying(true);
            audio.play();
            console.log("play")
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <audio
                    src={bgmsrc}
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                    playing={playing}
                />
                <IconContext.Provider value={{ // react-icons module
                    style: {
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%'
                    }
                }}>
                    {
                        playing ?
                        <AiFillPauseCircle onClick={handleAudioPlay} /> // react-icon
                        :
                        <AiFillPlayCircle onClick={handleAudioPlay} /> // react-icon
                    }
                </IconContext.Provider>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

thanks to your help :)

Comment: Hi ATRIIX,
Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you help with the error message, that will a pointer to what is wrong with your code.

Comment: hi @YusufAdeyemo  
**here is error message:**  
Type error: 'H5AudioPlayer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'H5AudioPlayer' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/runner/work/next-trepick-web/next-trepick-web/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Can i see where you import the library. I just made I simple demo using the library and it works. Check here https://playcode.io/884035/

Comment: Thanks for your sample code! :D   
but **my problem is here:**   
the library is working well in local environment but arised error when npm run build in AWS environment.

Comment: and I imported library where 'BackgroundMusic.tsx'.   
My Project logic is here:  **BackgroundMusic is imported in Layout**, **Layout is imported in mainPage**

Comment: ATRIIX, try https://howlerjs.com. It's super easy to use and integrate.

Comment: hi @Shofol, thanks to recommend library :) I'll try it!